# Ubuntu Server filesystem usage

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

df says my /dev/sda1 filesystem is almost full:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              8256952   7616516    221008  98% /
none                   3803676       116   3803560   1% /dev
none                   3942504         0   3942504   0% /dev/shm
none                   3942504        64   3942440   1% /var/run
none                   3942504         0   3942504   0% /var/lock
none                   3942504         0   3942504   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sdb             433455904    203016 411234584   1% /mnt
/dev/sdf             104806400   9539884  95266516  10% /vol
```

But I don't understand what is taking so much space. When I run `ncdu /` I get:

```
    2.0GiB  /usr                                                                                                                                                 
    1.2GiB  /var
  256.9MiB  /root
  132.4MiB  /lib
   24.4MiB  /boot
   24.3MiB  /home
   12.9MiB  /tmp
    7.8MiB  /bin
    7.5MiB  /sbin
    6.5MiB  /etc
e  16.0kiB  /lost+found
e   4.0kiB  /media
e   4.0kiB  /opt
e   4.0kiB  /selinux
e   4.0kiB  /srv
>   0.0  B  /dev
>   0.0  B  /mnt
>   0.0  B  /proc
>   0.0  B  /sys
>   0.0  B  /vol
@   0.0  B   initrd.img
@   0.0  B   initrd.img.old
@   0.0  B   vmlinuz
@   0.0  B   vmlinuz.old
@   0.0  B   lib64
```

I there something I miss ? Where is my space gone ?

Comment: Large file in the / directory? Also you are running ncdu as root? Stick a large file in a directory the user running ncdu does not have list access to and ncdu is not going to be able to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely culprit is a deleted file (or files) that are still open by a process. `du` only counts disk space usage in the directory tree you pass and since the file is no longer in the directory tree, it is not counted. `df` on the other hand counts filesystem usage which includes open file descriptors. To check running processes that have open file descriptors to deleted files, use:

```
lsof | grep "deleted"
```

Kill or restart any such processes you find (use the PID in the second column) and that should resolve the issue.

Comment: he is using ncdu, not du, though probably does the same.

Comment: Looks like simply regular `du` with an ncurses wrapper.

Comment: not quite, it sorts by default (du has no sort), caches so you can descend into a directory to view the largest to smallest there. It's more like a console/terminal version of kdirstat/Firelight/Baobab(Disk Usage analyzer in gnome)/windirstat without the pretty graphical map representation drawn.

Comment: Everything else you stated is true in that it operates the same way as du in terms of knowing what files are on the filesystem.

Comment: @Garrett Thanks, you made my day sir ! Apache had open file descriptors to many, many deleted log files.. hence the issue. Solved !